# Scheduled mating a good idea?

Tags: humans, aliens, reproduction

So far in my story the humans have completed the tour of the ship.

The aliens in my story run on very specific protocols and to them they are needed laws. However to the humans these protocols are unneeded and even wrong. However there is no rebellion because otherwise the aliens would most likely give them severe punishment(And I consider being teleported to a planet other than the planet that has dinosaurs a severe punishment, especially if it is a gas planet or very hot rocky planet).

Now 2 weeks later the humans are going to be separated into Diurnal and Nocturnal such that there is an equal distribution and then go into survival training.

This survival training covers everything from first aid and natural disasters to croc, shark, and dinosaur attacks. The ultimate challenge is a T rex attack.

Anyway this is survival training based on the planet that has dinosaurs. This survival training needs to be taken for every generation during the 800 year trip to this planet that is 400 light years away. Preferably a few years after college level just to get settled in.

The purpose of survival training besides passing knowledge on generation through generation is to get rid of the weak and promote the strong. Another way the aliens do this is not allowing for birth defects(genetic or otherwise).

Anyway, after the survival training the humans are allowed to reproduce. All males are allowed to reproduce but only females of reproductive age are allowed to reproduce.

The way I planned my story I was thinking of scheduled mating and thus scheduled pregnancy.

Here is what I was thinking:

First the humans are selected at random making sure that there are no diurnal x nocturnal pairs to minimize emotional upset but also maximize genetic diversity.

Then the humans go into a secondary sleeping quarters(the primary is just for sleep) and mate there multiple times during the fertile period of that month and sleep together for as long as the mating takes. No exchange from 1 male to another is allowed during this time.

Then later on(about a week later) the aliens not only do a pregnancy test but also make sure it is not ectopic(that is anywhere but the uterus) If it is ectopic the aliens first induce a miscarriage. If that doesn't work, they do microsurgery to reduce damage to the mother.

During the whole 10 week period between mating and the fetal stage, the aliens regularly check to see if the egg is developing properly. If the defect check is clear for that woman(in other words no external defects(They don't know of any internal defects that might be there)) then they do regular checks to make sure it is progressing the way it should. If the defect check isn't clear then once again a miscarriage is induced.

Once the baby is born they check for genetic diseases and internal defects(like for example the heart having only 1 ventricle). Babies with genetic diseases and internal defects aren't allowed to live long past the health check and maybe the first feeding, even if the defect might eventually heal on its own(like an open foramen ovale). These babies are killed with cold temperatures(not the same cold temperatures used to cryopreserve humans near the end of the trip) and studied to see if there was a genetic problem.

Any nonpregnant women during any part of this process mate again during their next fertile period(and this includes the ones that were pregnant but there was a problem with it so it had to end)

So is this scheduled mating a good idea or not?

Comment: Seems too story based, maybe a little broad.

Comment: Honestly, you seem to be crossing a lot of different wires in this story. You can entirely cut out the back story and how you kill the newborns - that was actually uncomfortable to read, and I felt it affected my take on the rest of the question. Just stick to the facts and present your idea: you have humans being kept on a leash by alien overlords and they want to impose scheduled "breeding" which doesn't take age, any feelings, or personal preference into account. Would it work? **Well, do they have a bloody choice?** Define what ***"works"*** means.

Comment: Also, how do the aliens plan to stop people "mating" the rest of the time?

Answer (score 1):

The TV show "Ascension" has a similar plotline. You should check it out, it might give you insight in how this could be done, and further inspiration.